# georeferencing results of `rio stack`

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm taking some Sentinel-2 imagery and trying to merge the different .jp2 files into one multiband GeoTIFF file. When I do

```
   rio info T08VNL_20220702T200859_B02.jp2
```

I get some terminal output that clearly shows that the file has been properly georeferenced. But when I do this:

```
   rio stack --rgb T08VNL_20220702T200859_B0{4,3,2}.jp2 image.tif
```

the resulting file has no coordinate reference system or bounds. I don't see any other command-line options when I do `rio stack --help` that give me the option to supply the CRS. I could use `rio edit-info` after the fact, but this seems so weird that I'm wondering if the problem exists between keyboard and chair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDALs [Sentinel2 driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/sentinel2.html#level-2a) exposes the data as subdatasets, with (sort of) one for each resolution.

To access the subdataset that contains the 10m bands to generate an RGB (dropping the NIR band), you could use something like the following:

```
rio stack SENTINEL2_L2A:S2A_MSIL2A_20220913T144741_N0400_R139_T19JCH_20220913T215857.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml:10m:EPSG_32719 --bidx 3,2,1 -o rgb.tif -f GTiff --co COMPRESS=LZW --co TILED=YES
```

Note `rio info` for some reason doesn't list the subdataset names, so use `gdalinfo` to list them.

```sh
gdalinfo S2A_MSIL2A_20220913T144741_N0400_R139_T19JCH_20220913T215857.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml 
Driver: SENTINEL2/Sentinel 2
<snip>
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=SENTINEL2_L2A:S2A_MSIL2A_20220913T144741_N0400_R139_T19JCH_20220913T215857.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml:10m:EPSG_32719

rio info SENTINEL2_L2A:S2A_MSIL2A_20220913T144741_N0400_R139_T19JCH_20220913T215857.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml:10m:EPSG_32719

{"blockxsize": 128, "blockysize": 128, "bounds": [300000.0, 6690220.0, 409800.0, 6800020.0], "colorinterp": ["red", "green", "blue", "undefined"], "compress": "jpeg2000", "count": 4, "crs": "EPSG:32719", "descriptions": ["B4, central wavelength 665 nm", "B3, central wavelength 560 nm", "B2, central wavelength 490 nm", "B8, central wavelength 842 nm"], "driver": "SENTINEL2", "dtype": "uint16", "height": 10980, "indexes": [1, 2, 3, 4], "lnglat": [-70.49565711534021, -29.414857874404007], "mask_flags": [["all_valid"], ["all_valid"], ["all_valid"], ["all_valid"]], "nodata": null, "res": [10.0, 10.0], "shape": [10980, 10980], "tiled": true, "transform": [10.0, 0.0, 300000.0, 0.0, -10.0, 6800020.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], "units": [null, null, null, null], "width": 10980}

rio info rgb.tif 
{"blockxsize": 256, "blockysize": 256, "bounds": [300000.0, 6690220.0, 409800.0, 6800020.0], "colorinterp": ["gray", "undefined", "undefined"], "compress": "lzw", "count": 3, "crs": "EPSG:32719", "descriptions": [null, null, null], "driver": "GTiff", "dtype": "uint16", "height": 10980, "indexes": [1, 2, 3], "interleave": "pixel", "lnglat": [-70.49565711534021, -29.414857874404007], "mask_flags": [["all_valid"], ["all_valid"], ["all_valid"]], "nodata": null, "res": [10.0, 10.0], "shape": [10980, 10980], "tiled": true, "transform": [10.0, 0.0, 300000.0, 0.0, -10.0, 6800020.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], "units": [null, null, null], "width": 10980}
```

Comment: I didn't know that GDAL had a Sentinel-2 driver, I'd just assumed that you have to operate on the image files individually. I found a way around the problem which I've also posted but your solution is probably better practice.

Answer (score 0):

@user2856 has a better answer but this also worked:

```
rio stack --rgb --driver GTiff T08VNL_20220702T200859_B0{4,3,2}.jp2 image.tif
```

I thought that by having an output file with a .tif extension, the GeoTIFF driver would get selected automatically. But apparently I needed to do that explicitly in order to get the georeferencing information included in the output file.